# C/C++ Library for Extracting Icons from Binaries

Tags: c++, windows, icons, shortcut, binaries

I'm planning on building a hotkey-activated application launcher for Windows. I intend for it to be a pop-up grid of icons in which you can then click and launch what you need. I'd like for it to automatically scan the Start Menu and Desktop for program shortcuts and catalog them. However, I'm not sure of how to go about the icon retrieval process from the shortcuts/actual binaries and I was wondering if there are any libraries for C/C++ that handle this sort of thing? If not, how would I go about it otherwise?

Comment: An executable file can contain many icons - you specifically want the one that Windows displays in the Start menu or Explorer, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `ExtractAssociatedIcon`

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648067%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but the `ExtractIcon` function looks like it might also be a good function to check out.

Comment: Nice! This looks like exactly what I need. I assume the index would be 0 for the icon I need right?

Answer (score 1):

[resources extract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html) is one such tool which extracts images from dll/ocx/exe files.

Well, if you do not want to use a closed source application, here is something with source, 
[Icon Extractor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconExtractor.aspx)

Comment: Interesting. I'd rather not use this as I'd have to be dependent on an external program and someone else's closed source code at that, but I think it'll work as a last resort if I can't find anything else. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

1. [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28VS.85%29.aspx) - use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`
2. [EnumResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648037%28VS.85%29.aspx) - to find the resource
3. [LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[LoadIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072%28VS.85%29.aspx) - to load the image/icon

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExctractIconEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-extracticonexa) to load the specified icon from the executable. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellicon.aspx) suggests checking for icon overrides in the registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons` if compatibility with the shell is desired.

Answer (score 1):

ExtractIconEx. Full source code is in my [open source project](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/#Download), file named icon.cpp. It supports expansion of system variables and getting a icon from an index, like `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\shell32.dll,43`

Here is the guts of it :

```
HICON GoFindAnIcon(LPCTSTR path)
{
    HICON icon = 0;

    //not using our parent's icon
    if(_tcsicmp(L"parent", path))
    {
        icon = (HICON)LoadImage(0, path, IMAGE_ICON, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_LOADMAP3DCOLORS);
        if(!icon)
        {
            //Try something else
            TCHAR mypath[MAX_PATH];
            const TCHAR *cleanpath = path;
            const TCHAR *comma;             

            comma = _tcsrchr(path, ',');
            UINT index = 1;

            if(comma)
            {
                _tcsncpy(mypath, path, comma-path); //Can you exploit this buffer overflow ?
                mypath[comma-path] = TCHAR(0);

                index = _ttoi(comma+1);

                cleanpath = mypath;
            }

            ExtractIconEx(cleanpath, index, 0, &icon, 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        icon = GetParentProcessIcon();
    }

    return icon;
}
```